# error while called third party API using Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am calling third party API using jquery AJAX and I am getting the following error

```
GET https://openweathermap.org/img/w/%22+%60$%7B$%7Bresponse.icon%7D%60+%22.png 404 (Not Found)
```

my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#main').submit(function(event){
  console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url:'/weather/',
        type:'POST',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#weather_output_box').html(`<p>${response.avg_temp}</p>);
            $('#weather_icon').attr('src','http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+`${response.icon}`+".png');
          }
    });
})
```

})

My Html file

```
<form id = 'main', action="{% url 'weather' %}",  method= 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
         <div>
           <input type="submit" name "submit" value="Get your weather">
         </div>
         <div class="box">
            <figure class="image is-50x50">
                <img id='weather_icon'>
             </figure>
             <table class="table"  name="wc" id="weather_output_box"></table>
          </div>
 </form>
```

the `response.avg_temp` is displayed but `response.icon` is the problem. I think that the value of `response.icon` is a not assigned properly here

Comment: The "strange" syntax highlighting in the question should already give you a first clue what the problem is. Another one could be the presence of the string `response.icon` in the URL instead of its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#weather_icon').attr('src','http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+`${response.icon}`+".png');
```

`${response.icon}` is not resolving correctly in your code.

Use it without `${}` and use simple string concatenation instead.

```
'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + response.icon + '.png'
```

Comment: I tried with out `${}` like `'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+response.icon+".png'`  and got `GET https://openweathermap.org/img/w/%22+response.icon+%22.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @anandbharani Please check your quotes (that's why the syntax highlighting in your question is wrong)

Comment: thank you I solved it using` 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+ `${response.icon}` +'.png'`